Is there a solution to fix the Android Editor window? (Android Studio Koala 2024.1.1 Patch 1)
I have recently upgraded Android Studio to Koala (2024.1.1). But the editor window looks like that:
Android studio koala 2024.1.1
Like only a quarter of it is displayed.
And if I clicked on something (the click is done to another thing).
I want to resolve this issue (full screen normally).
What should I do?
